# MVC parial view going to get method rather than post on submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post, partial-views

I have a partial view which shows a search box with a couple of options

```
model PatientSearchViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Patient", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
{
    <form class="form-inline">
        <label style="padding-right:20px;">Search for a patient</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SearchText, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Search...", autocomplete = "off" } })
        <div class="checkbox">
            <div class="checkbox" style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px;">
                <label>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ShowOnlyOpenClients) Show only open clients</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type='submit' name='seach' id='search-btn' class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Search</button>
    </form>
}
```

When the submit button is hit I want it to go to my method below with the search content already complete, however instead it goes to the HttpGet method which is bringing back a null for the PatientSearchViewModel.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(PatientSearchViewModel patient)
    {
        PatientSearchViewModel patientVM = GetSearchResults(patient);
        return View(patientVM);
    }
```

Can anyone explain how I can get this to work?

Comment: Your partial has nested forms which is invalid html and not supported (delete the `<form class="form-inline">` tag). I'm guessing this partial might also be nested inside `<form>` in the main view.

Answer (score 0):

I have executed the code snippet you pasted here and found that

1. As you are making the use of the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`
   attribute so you need to add the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken();` this
   statement in your `partial view` inside the
   `@using(Html.BeginForm()){ }` block.
2. One more thing make sure that your action method will be inside the
   `PatientController`.

**For your reference** (this is my code)

```
@model WebApplication.Models.PatientSearchViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Patient", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();

    <label style="padding-right:20px;">Search for a patient</label>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SearchText, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Search...", autocomplete = "off" } })
    <div class="checkbox">
        <div class="checkbox" style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px;">
            <label>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ShowOnlyOpenClients) Show only open clients</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type='submit' name='seach' id='search-btn' class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Search</button>
}
```

**Suggestion:** As you have used the `@using(Html.BeginForm())` which will any way going to convert to `<form>` tag so instead of using another `<form class="form-inline">` inside it is creating the confusion please you may remove it.

I hope this will solve your problem.